# Capture columns in plpgsql during UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am writing a trigger in plpgsql for Postgres 9.1. I need to be able to capture the column names that were issued in the SET clause of an UPDATE so I can record the specified action in an audit table. The examples in the Postgres documentation are simple and inadequate for my needs. I have searched the internet for days and I am unable to find any other examples that try to achieve what I want to do here.

I am on a tight schedule to resolve this soon. I don't know Tcl so pl/Tcl is out of the question for me at this point. pl/Perl may work but I don't know where to start with it. Also I wanted to find a way to accomplish this in pl/pgsql if at all possible for portability and maintenance. If someone can recommend a pl/Perl solution to this I would be grateful.

Here is the table structure of the target table that will be audited:

Note: There are many other columns in the record table but I have not listed them here in order to keep things simple. But the trigger should be able to record changes to any of the columns in the row.

```
CREATE TABLE record (
   record_id    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   lastname     text,
   frstname     text,
   dob          date,
   created      timestamp default NOW(),
   created_by   integer,
   inactive     boolean default false
);
create sequence record_record_id_seq;
alter table record alter record_id set default nextval('record_record_id_seq');
```

Here is my audit table:

```
CREATE TABLE record_audit (
   id                integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   operation         char(1) NOT NULL, -- U, I or D
   source_column     text,
   source_id         integer,
   old_value         text,
   new_value         text,
   created_date      timestamp default now(),
   created_by        integer
);
create sequence record_audit_id_seq;
alter table record_audit alter id set default nextval('record_audit_id_seq');
```

My goal is to record INSERTS and UPDATES to the record table in the record_audit table that will detail not only what the target record_id was (source_id) that was updated and what column was updated (source_column), but also the old_value and the new_value of the column.

I understand that the column values will have to be CAST() to a type of text. I believe I can access the old_value and new_value by accessing NEW and OLD but I am having difficulty figuring out how to obtain the column names used in the SET clause of the UPDATE query. I need the trigger to add a new record to the record_audit table for every column specified in the SET clause. Note, there are not DELETE actions as records are simply UPDATED to inactive = 't' (and thus recorded in the audit table)

Here is my trigger so far (obviously incomplete). Please forgive me, I am learning pl/pgsql as I go.

```
-- Trigger function for record_audit table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_record() RETURNS TRIGER AS $$
   DECLARE
      insert_table  text;
      ref_col       text; --how to get the referenced column name??

   BEGIN
      --
      -- Create a new row in record_audit depending on the operation (TG_OP)
      --
      IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

         -- old_value and new_value are meaningless for INSERTs. Just record the new ID.
         INSERT INTO record_audit 
            (operation,source_id,created_by) 
         VALUES
            ('I', NEW.record_id, NEW.created_by);


      ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

         FOR i in 1 .. TG_ARGV[0] LOOP
            ref_col := TG_ARGV[i].column; -- I know .column doesn't exist but what to use?

            INSERT INTO record_audit 
               (operation, source_column, source_id, old_value, new_value, created_by) 
            VALUES 
               ('U', ref_col, NEW.record_id, OLD.ref_col, NEW.ref_col, NEW.created_by); 
         END LOOP;

      END IF;
      RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored anyway since this is an AFTER trigger
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER record_audit_trig
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on record
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_record();
```

Thanks for reading this long and winding question!

Comment: Is it vital that you know what was in the SET. Because I don't think you can. Easy enough to log which fields changed though.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I need to be able to add one new record to record_audit for every column that was changed, which is why I wanted to be able to access the SET clause. You mention that it's easy enugh to log which fields changed. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot to get this information - not in PL level - probably it is possible in C.

Good enough solution is based on changed fields in records NEW and OLD. You can get list of fields from system tables ~ are related to table that is joined to trigger.

Comment: So perhaps the way to go would be to simply compare the values of NEW and OLD to see what changed. But then how to know which column was changed?

Comment: Google around hstore audit logging - that's the simplest way to get a (text representation) of changed columns.

Comment: After a great deal of research I've come to the conclusion that the easiest way, as Richard suggests, to solve this whole problem is by using the hstore data type. Since I am already running Postgres 9.1 it's trivial to install and I am quickly finding great uses for it inside my tigger functions. Thanks for the all suggestions. Especially yours Richard, for suggesting hstore.